# como crear funcion login para code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, model

hola tengo una duda de como podría crear una funcion login en codeigniter en la version 3.1.11 he creado el modelo de usuario con su crud pero ahora quiero un login pero no se como hacerlo esto es lo que llevo en el modelo y la segunda imagen seria parte del controller.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que el código lo agregues como texto no como imágenes y que avances tienes de la función login o que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

primero de todo que me organizaría el código para no tenerlo todo junto,imagino que trabajarás con MVC así que el redirect del login,lo cargaría desde el controlador siempre,aunque también puedes cargarlo con java script desde la vista.Un ejemplo sería esto:

`<?php

class Php extends CI_Controller {

function login($idioma=null)
{

```
  //   $this->config->set_item('language', 'spanish');      //   Setear dinámicamente el idioma que deseamos que ejecute nuestra aplicación
  if(!isset($_POST['maillogin'])){   //   Si no recibimos ningún valor proveniente del formulario, significa que el usuario recién ingresa.   
     $this->load->view('login');      //   Por lo tanto le presentamos la pantalla del formulario de ingreso.
  }
  else{                        //   Si el usuario ya pasó por la pantalla inicial y presionó el botón "Ingresar"
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('maillogin','e-mail','required|valid_email');      //   Configuramos las validaciones ayudandonos con la librería form_validation del Framework Codeigniter
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordlogin','password','required');
     if(($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)){            //   Verificamos si el usuario superó la validación
        $this->load->view('login');                     //   En caso que no, volvemos a presentar la pantalla de login
     }
     else{                                       //   Si ambos campos fueron correctamente rellanados por el usuario,
        $this->load->model('usuarios_model');
        $ExisteUsuarioyPassoword=$this->usuarios_model->ValidarUsuario($_POST['maillogin'],$_POST['passwordlogin']);   //   comprobamos que el usuario exista en la base de datos y la password ingresada sea correcta
        if($ExisteUsuarioyPassoword){   // La variable $ExisteUsuarioyPassoword recibe valor TRUE si el usuario existe y FALSE en caso que no. Este valor lo determina el modelo.
           echo "Validacion Ok<br><br><a href=''>Volver</a>";   //   Si el usuario ingresó datos de acceso válido, imprimos un mensaje de validación exitosa en pantalla
        }
        else{   //   Si no logró validar
           $data['error']="E-mail o password incorrecta, por favor vuelva a intentar";
           $this->load->view('login',$data);   //   Lo regresamos a la pantalla de login y pasamos como parámetro el mensaje de error a presentar en pantalla
        }
     }
  }
```

}
}
?>`